# illustrator - fill pattern does not translate with bounding box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

I have an EPS file of an imshow() plot that I generated from MATLAB using https://github.com/altmany/export_fig

I didn't have this problem before, but now when I open the heatmap plot in illustrator and attempt to move the plot around, the colors shift around as if it got somehow tiled and is not translating with the rest of the bounding box.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What version of Illustrator? Is `Transform Pattern Tiles` checked in the **Preferences**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that `Transform Pattern Tiles` is **checked** in the `Preferneces`.